# C# #import referenced a type from a missing type library; '__missing_type__' used as a placeholder

Tags: c#, com

In C# assembly I created the following class/interface and generated a A.tlb

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("9850B8CE-B71E-4C77-ABE6-94BEB8EA308E")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ITest
{
    [DispId(1)]
    string Foo();

}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("E9625332-FEB3-4B9D-AB01-9BAAF844F8F3")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Test : ITest
{
    public string Foo()
    {
        return "hi";
    }

}
```

In another managed assembly I did created class/interface and generated a B.tlb

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("EF77F05A-B644-4E46-9AD9-5CB2E87EE89E")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IJunk
{
    ITest Foo();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("D88BD554-4D58-49A2-9E0F-058D47CBE3CE")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Junk : IJunk
{
    public ITest Foo()
    {
        var i = new Test();
        return i;

    }
}
```

Finally in a native C++ I did an #import B.tlb

I am getting

Error   2   error C4772: #import referenced a type from a missing type library; '**missing_type**' used as a placehol

I saw this but it appeared to be straight C++ COM

[Any way to resolve C4772 errors without having to register DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773568/any-way-to-resolve-c4772-errors-without-having-to-register-dlls)

I tried to import A.tlb first and that didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This went wrong because you skipped a required step.  You must register A.dll with Regasm.exe *before* you try to generate B.tlb.  This writes keys in the `Typelib` and `Interface` registry key.  If you don't then Tlbexp cannot figure out that ITest is described by A.tlb and will omit the necessary `importlib("A.tlb")` directive in the type library for B.  Which then makes the #import directive in the C++ compiler fall over since it cannot figure out where ITest comes from.  #importing A.tlb first is not a workaround.

Other than running Regasm by hand, the simplest way to ensure this is done is by letting the build system take care of that.  Right-click your A project, Properties, Build tab, tick the "Register for COM interop" option.  VS however must run elevated to have registry write access.

Keeping the declarations in just one project avoids this problem.